How Should We Interpret the Plural and Present-Active-Imperative Forms in These New Testament Verses on Prayer?
The three following verses all get at similar concepts:
Matthew 7:7 (KJV)

Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you:

Mark 11:24 (KJV)

Therefore I say unto you, What things soever ye desire when ye pray, believe that ye receive them, and ye shall have them.

John 16:24 (KJV)

Hitherto have ye asked nothing in my name: ask, and ye shall receive, that your joy may be full.

In all three verses, the "you" (or rather the "ye") is plural. However, I am not sure whether to interpret the plurality to mean that everyone in the plurality must be praying communally or whether each of the persons in the plurality can pray for their own individual petitions.
Secondarily, the verbs (e.g., "Ask (Αἰτεῖτε)," "seek (ζητεῖτε)," "knock (κρούετε)") are all "Present Active Imperative." I'm not sure whether to interpret these as one-time events or as continuous events (i.e., "be asking" or "ask once")

The Decalogue (Exodus 20, Deut. 5) has a similar issue in that it is second person singular.  If the singular means God is addressing Israel as a whole, then it would follow that with the plural Jesus was addressing the whole as individuals. The promise with the command to honor your father and mother makes the most sense if the singular addresses Israel as a whole.

Honor your father and your mother, that you may long endure on the land that the LORD your God is assigning to you.
(Ex 20:12, JPS1985)


long endure Respect for parents is deemed to be vital for the preservation of the social fabric; dishonoring parents imperils the well-being of society. --
Sarna, N. M. (1991). Exodus (p. 113). Jewish Publication Society.


14. Thou shalt not commit adultery [לֹא תִּנְאָף] —a word used with reference both to man and woman (cf. Lev. 20:10); and although the verb is in the second person singular masculine, like the rest of these commandments, this precept must be taken in the comprehensive sense of the term (Matt. 5:32). --
Brown, D., Fausset, A. R., & Jamieson, R. (n.d.). A Commentary, Critical, Experimental, and Practical, on the Old and New Testaments: Genesis–Deuteronomy: Vol. I (p. 360). William Collins, Sons, & Company, Limited.


upon the land —i. e., that thou mayest live long in the land; said either of the Israelites collectively, that if they were distinguished by a race of obedient children they would enjoy a lengthened possession of the land of promise, or with regard to individuals, ... --
Ibid., Vol. I (p. 359)


Greek TensesIn the Koine Greek language, the present tense implies a "continuous action". Thus, this verse may be translated as : ask, and keep on asking, seek and keep on seeking, knock, and keep on knocking.
The thought and emphasis of Jesus is habitual prayer, or perseverance in praying.  Recall that Jesus did not sin, when in the Garden of Gethsemene, He repeated a prayer three times! The Apostles asked congregations "to keep on praying for them" and the effectiveness of their ministry.
Character of GodHowever note, that by several parables, Jesus---while noting that there are instances where consistent asking (praying) is required---stated that God is more than willing to answer prayers since we are His children! It's just that God knows when and how to answer them to our best advantage. And out of His paternal love God would never give an undesirable answer to His child! (e.g. serpent for bread)
Remember the constant pleading of Blind Bartemaeus for healing...that was answered eventually. And the persistence of the Phoenician mother of Tyre in asking Jesus  to heal her daughter...which He finally did!
Note, for example, the prayers of the amazing prophet Daniel. On an occasion, the answer to a prayer was hindered by spiritual warfare among the angelic beings. (chapter 10) That did not mean that God wasn't concerned; it was that there is more to answered prayer than our own verbage, even in desperation. But God still sees, and still hears!
He even sees and hears even when, as in the case of Hagar, all that was offered were cries and tears. (See Genesis story.)
Plural 'You'The Bible recorded instances where either communal prayer or individual praying was appropriate...and responded to. The huddled disciples prayed when persecuted (See Acts references); and Paul prayed just himself for his converts (See Epistles). There are no requirements either way. That should help us exegete the posted scripture here.
The teaching of Jesus is that you all who are called Christians ought to pray in faith, and not give up.
